# Write module index to file with pydoc without server

Tags: python, documentation, pydoc

I currently write documentation for my Python library using the following command:

```
python -m pydoc -w "\\myserver.com\my_library"
```

This works fine, and I find in `my_library` HTML files with documentation derived from class / method / function docstrings. This even documents Python files found in subfolders.

I would now like to create and save an **index** which gives access to all these files.

The `pydoc` documentation says this is possible if you start a server:

> **pydoc -b** will start the server and additionally open a web browser to
>   a **module index page**. Each served page has a navigation bar at the top
>   where you can Get help on an individual item, Search all modules with
>   a keyword in their synopsis line, and go to the **Module index**, Topics
>   and Keywords pages.

However, I'm looking to write a Module Index page, including *relative* links to single file documentation, without the server solution. I can then store the Index + single files [one for each py file] in a directory accessible to users.

Is this possible, or is there a better way to approach this problem?

I have looked at Sphinx but this seems overkill for my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be basically achieved by running a small script:

- that imports the to be documented modules,
- writes the documentation to html files and then
- writes the output of the internal function that dynamically generates the index.html to a file index.html.

It is not a super nice solution because it relies on internals of the `pydoc` module, but is reasonably compact:

```
import pydoc
import importlib

module_list = ['sys']
for m in module_list:
    importlib.import_module(m)
    pydoc.writedoc(m)

#the monkey patching optionally goes here

with open('index.html','w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(pydoc._url_handler('index.html'))
```

There is another flaw with this is, in that it also creates links to all the builtin modules, etc. for which we did not (and did not want to, I guess) generate documentation for.

Can we copy the function from `pydoc.py` that creates the index.html file and modify it to only add links for our desired modules? Unfortunately, this is not straight forward, because the function uses some non-local scope to achieve some of its logic.

The next best solution would be to monkey-patch the `index_html()` method that generates this page to only list our modules.

Unfortunately `pydoc._url_handler` uses a local function to implement this and not a class method. So it becomes a bit tricky from here.

There is a solution to monkey patch, but it is a bit of a hack:

before calling the `_url_handler` we need to:

- define a patched version that only generates links for elements in our module_list (the detour via `__placeholder__` is used because our module_list is not defined in the scope where the function runs, so we need to do something that corresponds to hard-coding into the function, sort of.)
- patch the source of the `pydoc` module to use that local function instead of the originally defined

This is achieved by the following:

```
import inspect, ast

__placeholder__ = None

#our patched version, needs to have same name and signature as original
def html_index():
    """Module Index page."""
    names= __placeholder__

    def bltinlink(name):
        return '<a href="%s.html">%s</a>' % (name, name)

    heading = html.heading(
        '<big><big><strong>Index of Modules</strong></big></big>',
        '#ffffff', '#7799ee')
    contents = html.multicolumn(names, bltinlink)
    contents = [heading, '<p>' + html.bigsection(
        'Module List', '#ffffff', '#ee77aa', contents)]

    contents.append(
        '<p align=right><font color="#909090" face="helvetica,'
        'arial"><strong>pydoc</strong> by Ka-Ping Yee'
        '&lt;ping@lfw.org&gt;</font>')
    return 'Index of Modules', ''.join(contents)

#get source and replace __placeholder__ with our module_list
s=inspect.getsource(html_index).replace('__placeholder__', str(module_list))

#create abstract syntax tree, and store the actual function definition in l_index
l_index=ast.parse(s).body[0]
#ast.dump(l_index) #check if you want

#now obtain source from unpatched pydoc, generate ast patch it and recompile:
s= inspect.getsource(pydoc)
m = ast.parse(s)

def find_named_el_ind(body, name):
    '''find named element in ast body'''
    found=False
    for i,e in enumerate(body):
        if hasattr(e,'name') and e.name == name:
            found=True
            break
    if not found: raise ValueError('not found!')
    return i

#find and replace html_index with our patched html_index
i_url_handler = find_named_el_ind(m.body, '_url_handler')
i_html_index = find_named_el_ind(m.body[i_url_handler].body, 'html_index')
m.body[i_url_handler].body[i_html_index] = l_index

#compile and replace module in memory
co = compile(m, '<string>', 'exec')
exec(co, pydoc.__dict__)

#ast.dump(m.body[i_url_handler]) #check ast if you will
```

Comment: Thank you! Surprising pydoc doesn't support index creation as an option. I haven't had a chance to test / implement your solution, but will let you know as soon as I can.

Comment: Glad I could help, let me know if you have any issues, this worked for me on Ubuntu python 3.7.